How to verbalise t test results
I'm reading up on statistics and yesterday I asked the question why the two different t tests give different results.
statmerkur gave the following answer

There is no contradiction. The rejection region for your two-sided $t$-test is given by
$$
\left(-\infty, t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778)\right] \cup \left[-t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778), \infty\right) \approx \left(-\infty, -5.2\right] \cup \left[5.2, \infty\right),
$$
where $t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778)$ is the $0.05 / 2 = 0.025$ quantile of Student's $t$ distribution with $1.6778$ degrees of freedom.

but I don't understand the mathematical background. I would like to use this ("decoded") knowledge to transfer it to other t tests and thus interpret other data (which I have not presented in the question).

Your question is unclear: could you please explain how you conceive of applying the result of a t-test "to other data"?

@whuber sorry I expressed myself unhappily! I hope it is now more clear :)

Is there a page where I can ask this type of question?

Your test statistic (in your case $t = 5.194$) is following a Student-t distribution. You get this test statistic through different ways (e.g., testing a regression coefficient against a critical value boils down to $t=\frac{\hat{\beta} - c}{\hat{se}(\hat{\beta})}$ but formulas look different when testing two means for equality arising from two samples against each other). More formally, a variable follows the Student-t distribution
$t = \frac{z}{\sqrt{V/p}} \sim t(p)$
where $z \sim N(0,1)$ follows a standard normal distribution and $V \sim \chi^2(p)$ a Chi-squared distribution with $p$ degrees of freedom.
Each distribution can be characterized by its probability density function (pdf) and cumulative density function (cdf, also called cumulative distribution function). Grossly speaking, the pdf provides you with a value for any given sample (or point) that we can interpret as relative likelihood. The cdf provides you with the probability that a random variable $X$ will take a value less than or equal to $x$.
More formally,
$F_X(x) = \int^x_{-\infty} f_X(u) du$,
where $F_X(x)$ denotes the cdf and $f_X(x)$ the pdf. You can think of summing up all the relative likelihoods from $-\infty$ to $x$. Graphically speaking, this means the area under the curve from $-\infty$ to $x$ providing you with a probability statement. In the picture below you see a pdf (called $f(x)$) and the marked area under the curve from $-\infty$ to $3$. $F(3)$ denotes then the probability that the random variable $X$ is 3 or below.

We can also express the probability between two values as follows
$Pr[a \leq X \leq b] = \int^b_a f_X(x) dx$,
which just states the probability of the random variable $X$ being in the interval between the two values, $a$ and $b$.
This brings us back to t-testing. What exactly do we want to achieve? In a two-tailed t-test, we test for the equality of means. Therefore, we set up the following null and alternative hypothesis:
$H_0: \quad X_1 = X_2$,
$H_1: \quad X_1 \neq X_2$.
Given the significance level of $\alpha = 0.05$, we conduct want to find out whether the t value (or t statistic) is within the critical values of the t-distribution. We know that the t-distribution is only characterized by one parameter, the degrees of freedom. Those are given by $p=1.6778$. Then we use the cdf to find the critical values which cover $0.05/2$ probability mass at the tails of the distribution (since we use a two-sided t-test we want to cut on both sides of the distribution).

The Student-t distribution is symmetric, so the left critical value is equal in absolute value to the right critical value. We combine
$Pr[t \geq t_c] = \frac{\alpha}{2}$
$Pr[t \leq t_c] = \frac{\alpha}{2}$
and when we combine we get
$Pr[-t_c \leq t \leq t_c] = 1-\alpha$
We find the following interval in this case as, $Pr[-5.200078 \leq t \leq 5.200078]$. You can use the R command qt(0.025, 1.6778) to find the first value (and correspondingly also the second). Since the t-statistic in our case is $t=5.194$, this means we are within this region and we cannot reject the null hypothesis. Finally, we can derive the rejection region, which was stated in your question as exactly the remaining region:
$(- \infty,-5.200078) \, \cup \, (5.200078,\infty)$.
Obviously, the t-statistic is not within the rejection region because we have already shown that it is within the acceptance region.
